# alias_attribute vs read_attribute and write_attribute

Tags: ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I'm using ActiveRecord without rails.  Everything works fine except for a weird quirk with some helper methods I'm writing that I'm hoping someone can explain.  I've got a model of a legacy database.  Some columns names have a "#" in them so I defined them in the model using read_attribute and write_attribute.  For example (accurate example but simplified):

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  alias_attribute :name, :pname

  def sale_number
    read_attribute 'sale#'
  end

  def sale_number=(value)
    write_attribute 'sale#', value
  end

  def self.helper_with_alias
    where(name: 'My Product Name')
  end

  def self.helper_with_attribute
    where(sale_number: 5)
  end
end
```

If I call `Product.helper_with_alias` everything works as expected.  But when I call `Product.helper_with_attribute` I get a `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid` error saying that the column `sale_number` could not be found.  In addition, if I replace the code in `helper_with_attribute` to `where('sale#' => 5)` everything works fine.

Why does ActiveRecord correctly alias `pname` to `name` but not correctly alias `sale#` to `sale_number`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because you are using an in-existent column in the where clause.  You also need to define alias_attribute for `sale#` to `sale_number`.

In your model, you can do:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  alias_attribute :sale_number, :"sale#"

  def self.helper_with_attribute
    where(sale_number: 5)
  end
end
```

With this you don't need to define setters and getters just for assignment and retrieval purposes, so you can remove `sale_number` and `sale_number=(value)` methods.  With `alias_attribute`, [*getters*, *setters* and *query methods*](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/aliasing.rb#L62) are already aliased!

> Why does ActiveRecord correctly alias pname to name but not correctly
>   alias sale# to sale_number?

This is because you have defined `alias_attribute :name, :pname` which provided the setters, getters and query methods as alias to your existing `pname` attribute.  But, for `sale_number`, you've only defined a getter and setter but not the query methods.